# Rails subdomains and default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, subdomain

I have a working app. I want to add subdomains that will serve the same app, but with different data. I added a subdomain field in one Foo table, and foreign keys pointing to this Foo table wherever I wanted data to be filtered by subdomain, for example the Bar table has a foo_id added.

ApplicationController has a before_filter that sets @foo:

```
foos = Foo.where(subdomain: request.subdomain)
@foo = foos.first if foos.count > 0
```

I want Bar model to have a default scope using @foo, so that I don't have to change all the places where I'm calling for Bar.

```
default_scope { where(foo: @foo) }
```

This works perfectly for the no-subdomain url, where @foo is nil and the app only shows data where foo_id is NULL. But it doesn't for subdomains, the default_scope still picks NULL foo_id even though pry lets me see that @foo is set correctly.

So is it impossible to use an instance variable from AppController in a model scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in Railscast #388 http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

Go with class methods for Foo, tracking current_id, so the default scope becomes:

```
default_scope { where(foo_id: Foo.current_id) }
```